# INSERT ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET (an UPSERT) statement with a unique constraint is generating constraint violations when run concurrently

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to run an Postgres `UPSERT` in fairly concurrent code. I have been seeing a `duplicate key value violates unique constraint` error when my service is under load.

By way of a reduced example, I have the following table, which has an `id` primary key and an `id_secondary` unique key (meant to function as a second ID)

```sql
CREATE TABLE "test_table" (
    "id" text NOT NULL,
    "id_secondary" text NOT NULL,
    "value" bool NOT NULL DEFAULT 'FALSE',
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "test_table_uc" ON "public"."test_table" USING BTREE ("id_secondary");
```

I am running the following two statements simultaneously:

```sql
INSERT INTO "test_table" ("id", "id_secondary", "value") VALUES('1', '1', 'false') 
ON CONFLICT ("id")
  DO UPDATE
  SET "value" = "excluded"."value";

INSERT INTO "test_table" ("id", "id_secondary", "value") VALUES('1', '1', 'true') 
ON CONFLICT ("id")
  DO UPDATE
  SET "value" = "excluded"."value";
```

and it is my expectation that whichever statement executes last will be the one to set the value of `"value"`.

Occasionally I am receiving the error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_table_uc"` from one of these statements. My full test setup in Go (using testify) is:

```golang
suite.Run("Concurrency", func() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=35432 dbname=test sslmode=disable user=postgres")
    db.SetMaxOpenConns(10)
    suite.Require().NoError(err)

    for ii := 0; ii < 100; ii++ {
        wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
        wg.Add(2)

        go func() {
            _, err := db.Exec(`
                    INSERT INTO "test_table" ("id", "id_secondary", "value") VALUES($1, $2, 'false') 
                    ON CONFLICT ("id")
                        DO UPDATE
                            SET
                                "value" = "excluded"."value"
                `, ii, ii)
            suite.Require().NoError(err)
            wg.Done()
        }()

        go func() {
            _, err := db.Exec(`
                    INSERT INTO "test_table" ("id", "id_secondary", "value") VALUES($1, $2, 'true') 
                    ON CONFLICT ("id") 
                        DO UPDATE
                            SET
                                "value" = "excluded"."value"
                `, ii, ii)
            suite.Require().NoError(err)
            wg.Done()
        }()
        wg.Wait()
    }
})
```

Where I am allowing concurrent SQL connections using `db.SetMaxOpenConns(10)` and the `go func()` syntax is running both SQL statements in different goroutines (threads). Only two of the statements are run at a time, and the value of `"id"` and `"id_secondary"` are always set to the loop iteration. I wait for both statements to return before iterating.

It generally fails with the `duplicate key value violates unique constraint` error within a few loops.

I have not modified my isolation settings and I am running in `SHOW default_transaction_isolation = read committed`, on PostgreSQL 9.6.24

### My Question

At no point is the statement generating a row that does not satisfy the unique constraints of the table. Seemingly, both statements are attempting to insert data at the same time. The Postgres documentation states that:

> ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE guarantees an atomic INSERT or UPDATE outcome; provided there is no independent error, one of those two outcomes is guaranteed, even under high concurrency. This is also known as UPSERT — “UPDATE or INSERT”.
> which I interpreting to mean that the INSERT or UPDATE happens atomically, they should never attempt to write in data with the same primary key.

For the `test_table_uc` constraint to be violated, then in my example, the primary key uniqueness constraint must also be breaking. This is very surprising to me.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you really insert the exact same value in `id` and `id_secondary` in your actual code?

Comment: No, in my actual code `id` and `id_secondary` form a composite ID (with a unique constraint to enforce it), but `id` is still used as the primary key. In this reduced example I left the additional unique constraint just on a single column `id_secondary` as it didn't change the error. I'm setting them to the same value here to reduce the example as much as possible too, since if `id_secondary` conflicts then `id` definitely will conflict too.

Comment: Then your example does not actually illustrate your issue. If `id` is unique then a composite unique index does is useless for enforcement - anything column combination containing `id` will be unique. (Composite key may be useful for performance of some queries).

Comment: I think standard `UPSERT` statements seemingly not behaving atomically when there are multiple unique constraints is surprising behavior, and my question is an attempt to find out why, rather than trying to get my use-case working, which is why I haven't elaborated too deeply on my use-case in the question. I think it is a well formed question by itself.

I agree with your logic, and deleting `test_table_uc` would likely fix my issue. However, this would require rewriting the ORM I am using, something I'd prefer not to have to do without knowing why the statements in my example do not work.

Comment: I have modified my question to add a question statement at the bottom

Comment: Is there a difference if you use the other index for the upsert, i.e. `ON CONFLICT (id, id_secondary)`? I wonder if there is a fixed order in which the constraints are checked (alphabetically by name, like triggers?) or whether they're checked in parallel.

Comment: If I modify `test_table_uc` to be a composite index on `id` and `id_secondary` so I can run `ON CONFLICT (id, id_secondary)` it still fails, but this time on `violates unique constraint "test_table_pkey"`. It seems to fail on the constraint not mentioned in the `ON CONFLICT`

Comment: I have just tested this on every isolation level, it is the same across them all except for `repeatable read` where the error turns into `could not serialize access due to concurrent update`. This is probably a clue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading through the Postgres source code I believe I have found a satisfying answer to this.

In the `ON CONFLICT` statements given, only `id` is mentioned as a column. This will cause Postgres to use `test_table_pkey` as an arbiter index.

Normally, when evaluating an `ON CONFLICT` Postgres will speculatively insert the new row, and check only the arbiter indexes for conflicts (against currently committed rows) using `ExecCheckIndexConstraints`. If there is a conflict on `test_table_pkey` and `test_table_uc` it will only be checking for the arbiter index `test_table_pkey`, which will have a conflict and cause Postgres to revert to the `ON CONFLICT` clause.

If two of these `INSERT` expressions are occurring at the same time, neither will see each other (as they are both speculative and both pass `ExecCheckIndexConstraints`). This will cause Postgres to attempt to commit both speculative rows. The first row will commit properly. The second row will cause two constraint violations during `ExecInsertIndexTuples`. The function `ExecInsertIndexTuples` will suppress errors on any *arbiter indexes only*, meaning that the constraint violation on `test_table_pkey` will get caught (and cause Postgres to retry the insert from the top), but the `test_table_uc` violation will become an uncaught error which causes the statement to error.

Essentially, this means if your upsert is potentially causing conflicts on constraints that are not named in the `ON CONFLICT` clause, these statements will fail, **but only during concurrent inserts**.

Comment: This is helpful and explains the behaviour, but what would be the solution to hopefully bypass this problem ?